# Palindrome Number in java script

Tags: javascript

Given an integer x, return true if x is a
palindrome
, and false otherwise.

Example 1:

Input: x = 121
Output: true
Explanation: 121 reads as 121 from left to right and from right to left.
Example 2:

Input: x = -121
Output: false
Explanation: From left to right, it reads -121. From right to left, it becomes 121-. Therefore it is not a palindrome.
Example 3:

Input: x = 10
Output: false
Explanation: Reads 01 from right to left. Therefore it is not a palindrome.

Ans :

```
var isPalindrome = function(number) {
     if(number.toString() === number.toString().split("").reverse().join("")){
        return true
    }
 return false;
};
```

How to optimize more and reduse time complexity

Comment: If you're looking for speed, then I would keep track of indexies instead of reversing the string. One index starts at the back, and then one in the front. If the two characters are the same, continue by moving both pointers towards the center. If both are at the same index or they pass each other then you can finish comparing them.

Comment: insted of `if (....)` and 2 returns, just `return (number.toString() === number.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));` not sure if this optimizes / time reduces anything. I mean, as of now your code is like "if condition is true, return true, else return false"... just return condition and you're done

Comment: @Jordan Since JS integers can be at most about 15 digits, I don't think that's going to make a significant difference.

Comment: You can't reduce the time complexity, it will always be O(n), where `n` is the number of digits in the number.

Comment: And since n has a relatively small limit, that makes it effectively O(1). Big-O analysis generally only makes sense when n is effectively unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which time complexity does the `reverse` function have (but I think it is O(n)).

However, below it's a function that does not use any string manipulation builtin but compares the digits starting from the indices in the middle of your number and then moves to the ones next to those, and so on, until it reaches the beginning/end of the number or it doesn't find equal digits. It runs in O(n) (technically n/2 as worst case scenario when the number is palindrome).

```js
function isPalindrome(num) {
  if (num < 0) {
    return false
  } else {
    let len = num.toString().length
    let i, j
    if ((len%2) === 1) { //Odd number of digits
      i = len/2 - 1.5
      j = len/2 + 0.5
    } else {
      i = len/2 - 1
      j = len/2
    }
    while (num[i] === num[j]) {
      if (i == 0) {
        return true
      }
      i-=1
      j+=1
    }
    return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The palindrome algo is quite easy, just iterate characters from the beginning and the end of a string and compare, convert your number to a string first:

```js
function isNumPalindrome(num){
  const str = Math.abs(num).toString();
  for(let i=0, j=str.length-1; i<j; i++,j--){
    if(str[i] !== str[j]){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

[123, 121, 121.121, 233332, 12332123, -123321].forEach(num => console.log(num, '=>', isNumPalindrome(num)));
```

And benchmark:

```
` Chrome/118
------------------------------------------------------------
small array
    Alexander   1.00x  |  x10000000  798  826  832  847  847
    Koolinc     1.47x  |   x1000000  117  117  120  122  132
big array
    Alexander   1.00x  |  x10  210  215  215  219  225
    Koolinc     1.19x  |  x10  249  253  256  257  268
------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const arr = [121, 2341, -122, 2332, 1221, 1, 127721, -1213121];

const bigArr = Array.from({ length: 1_000_000 }, () =>
  Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 1000000)
);

function reverseDigits(nr) {
  let reversed = 0;
  
  while (nr > 0) {
    reversed = reversed * 10 + nr % 10;
    nr = Math.floor(nr / 10);
  }
  
  return reversed;
}


function isPalindrome(nr) {
  nr = Math.abs(nr);
  return nr < 10 ? `n/a` : nr === reverseDigits(nr);
}

function isNumPalindrome(num){
  const str = Math.abs(num).toString();
  for(let i=0, j=str.length-1; i<j; i++,j--){
    if(str[i] !== str[j]){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

// @group small array

// @benchmark Koolinc
arr.forEach(isPalindrome);
true;

// @benchmark Alexander
arr.forEach(isNumPalindrome);
true;

// @group big array

// @benchmark Koolinc
bigArr.forEach(isPalindrome);
true;

// @benchmark Alexander
bigArr.forEach(isNumPalindrome);
true;


/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse a number without (relative slow) string manipulation you can use a function that uses arithmetic for it:

```js
[121, 2341, -122, 2332, 1221, 1, 127721, -1213121]
  .forEach( nr => console.log(`${nr} ${isPalindrome(nr)}`));

function reverseDigits(nr) {
  let reversed = 0;
  
  while (nr > 0) {
    reversed = reversed * 10 + nr % 10;
    nr = Math.floor(nr / 10);
  }
  
  return reversed;
}

function isPalindrome(nr) {
  nr = Math.abs(nr);
  return nr < 10 ? `n/a` : nr === reverseDigits(nr);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: seems not so fast, check a benchmark in my answer...

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev [Are you sure](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fpjipv?file=index.js)?

Comment: your benchmark isn't pure, you make random number generation while benchmarking. I've put your case into my benchmark with preparing numbers ahead plus 30ms is small and fluctuates more, my func is faster again, but the difference is smaller.

Comment: I've factored the random numbers out of the [test](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fpjipv?file=index.js). Anyway, the differences are quite marginal, so I would say: pick what suits you.

Comment: agree, the difference is small for real case scenarios. the only difference that my func handles decimals, but that  could be consider optional